# Export actions(animations) to FBX and open in Unity

Tags: python, animation, constraints

I have a Problem with animating objects in Blender.

When I add the constraint "Follow_Path" to my objects and then bake animation, I have about seven additional Actions for one object.

The animation works very nice, but when I open the FBX format in Unity, I get all these actions and only one is the right one. For example Action.007

Mabye, I do something wrong with the selection?

Actions in Unity:

[image: actions]

Here some Code:

```
def followPath():
    for object in scene.objects:
        scene.objects.active = object
        object.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='FOLLOW_PATH')
        # Settings
        forward_axis = getForwardAxis(path)#I get the path from another function
        up_axis = getUpAxis(path)
        constraint = bpy.data.objects[object.name].constraints["Follow Path"]
        constraint.target = bpy.data.objects[path.name]
        constraint.forward_axis = forward_axis
        constraint.up_axis = up_axis
        constraint.use_curve_follow = True
        # animate the path
        override = {'constraint': object.constraints["Follow Path"]}
        bpy.ops.constraint.followpath_path_animate(override, constraint='Follow Path')
        bakeAnimation()
        object.select = False

def bakeAnimation():
    bpy.ops.nla.bake(frame_start=1, frame_end=250, only_selected=True,
                 visual_keying=True, clear_constraints=True, clear_parents = True, bake_types={'OBJECT'})
```

Comment: Can you post more of your script.  Eg what is `bakeAnimation()`.  Suggest using `constraint = obj.constraints.new(type='FOLLOW_PATH')`

Comment: Nothing changes with your suggestions.

My main question is, why are there so many actions, while I only made one per object?

Comment: did you check the action editor to see if they are there as well? You can try delete them from there.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was not exactly the solution but I have it now.

Answer (score 2):

I have the answer now:

The first problem is, that I don't clear the old actions when I start the script twice. Therefore, it appends the new actions to the old ones.
Now in Blender there are only the needed actions.

However, when I Export it to FBX and open it in Unity I have the same problem.

You have to push the action down to a new strip:
Open the NLA-Editor and push that button next to your action.

[image]

For the export you have to select the following:

[image]

When you open your FBX in Unity there is only one action for each object.

How you do it in python:

```
#Add NLA-Strip
bpy.context.area.type = "NLA_EDITOR"
bpy.ops.nla.action_pushdown(channel_index = 1)#choose your index
#Export Settings 
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath = yourfilepath,
                         use_selection=True,
                         bake_anim_use_all_bones = False,
                         bake_anim_use_nla_strips=True,
                         bake_anim_use_all_actions=False
                         )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.90 you want to search for the "Nonlineair Animations" window, the buttons looks a bit different now as in Matt's answer. You need to click it, and then export with like in Matt's screenshot (All Actions disabled).

FBX imported in Unity 2019.4.8f1, multiple objects each with an animation, where all animations are shown in duplicate:

[image: Before in Unity 2019.4.8f1]

Blender 2.90:
[image: Blender 2.90]

This is how it looks after clicking the button above
[image: After clicking 'push down action']

Export the FBX with "All actions" disabled and then importing in Unity:
[image: After exporting with 'All Actions' disabled]